# if let a = b, a.something() else

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have a code snippet here that works but am curious if there is a *cleaner* way to accomplish the same thing. I haven't seen anything exactly like this so far.

**Logic I want to Achieve**

- The `error` is `nil` or is not a `SpecialError`
- The `error` is `non-nil` ***BUT*** `.foo()` returns `false`

**Code**

```
enum SpecialError: Error {
    func foo() -> Bool
}

let error: Error? // Some optional Error is passed in

if let myError = error as? SpecialError, myError.foo() {
    // Don't care about this case
} else {
    // This is the case I'm interested in
    bar()
}
```

I'm curious if there is a better way to accomplish this `if let else` logic.

Comment: Great question! I appreciate the effort, rather than just settling for leaving the `if` block empty and only using the `else` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you want is for when the expression `(error as? SpecialError)?.foo()` evaluates
 to either:

1. `nil`, in which case `error` is not a `SpecialError`, or is `nil`.
2. `false`, in which case `error` is a `SpecialError`, but `foo()` returned `false`.

In your case, one way to express this is by taking advantage of the fact that the equality operators are overloaded for optionals, and saying:

```
if (error as? SpecialError)?.foo() != true {
    bar()
}
```

As we're using the overload of [`!=`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1540260) that compares optionals, `true` will be promoted to a `Bool?`, so we're checking that `(error as? SpecialError)?.foo()` is not a `.some(true)`, which in this case is equivalent to checking if it is `.some(false)` or `.none`.

Comment: This is comparing an Optional<Bool> with a bool, no? or did they add that overload?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ It's comparing a `Bool?` with a `Bool?` (using [this overload](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1540260)) – `true` gets promoted to an optional here. So it's checking that `(error as? SpecialError)?.foo()` is not a `.some(true)`, i.e a `.some(false)` or `.none`

Comment: Ah...they must of added some inference there. Also, you should be able to just add ! in front, rather than comparing it to true

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ No, the prefix `!` operator doesn't work with a `Bool?` operand

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding, but it seems like nothing happens in the first branch of the `if` statement and you want to cut it down to just the second part?  In that case, this should work for you:

```
if !((error as? SpecialError)?.foo() ?? false) {
    bar()
}
```

This will execute `bar()` if:
1. `error` is nil
2. `error` is not a `SpecialError`
3. `foo()` returns false

Comment: This works great and was about to accept it as the answer but saw Hamish's error which looks a little nicer to me. Thanks though! +1'd

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're probably looking for something like this:

`if !((error as? SpecialError)?.foo() ?? false) {`

Answer (score 1):

How about translating it exactly as you explained it:

```
if error == nil || !(error! is SpecialError) || !error!.foo() {
    bar()
}
```

The short-circuiting of *or* will prevent the *force unwraps* of `error` from being a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is hard to read, and John Montgomery's code is even harder to read and I predict it will be hard to maintain: imagine another developer looking at this code a year from now and asking you what it is doing, or even worse, that developer cannot ask you as you are no longer available. Imagine yourself looking at this code even even a couple months from now.

`if let myError = error as? SpecialError, myError.foo()` is convoluted, perhaps being a bit too clever. It contains too much logic to be long term readable by a team of developers.

Your first block could just check if *myError is nil*

Your second block could just check if *is myError of type SpecialError*

```
//you could use a guard statement here
if myError == nil {
     return;
}

if let myError = error as? SpecialError {
    //ok myError is type SpecialError it has a foo method I can call
    if(myError.foo()) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
} else { //myError not type SpecialError and is not nil
    // This is the case I'm interested in
    bar()
}
```

Comment: I have to disagree, I don't think there's anything convoluted about having multiple conditions in a single line.  Your code is good if there's something to execute in the first `else` block (i.e. some distinction needs to be made between the two conditions), but otherwise it's just an unnecessary pyramid.  I would strongly prefer the original question's code if that `else` isn't needed, and mine was written with the assumption that the entire first `if` block was empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let theFoo = (error as? SpecialError)?.foo(){
       if theFoo != true{
           bar()
       } //in case you want to do handling if theFoo is true
   } //in case you want to do handling if error is not SpecialError
```